# "There was an unexpected server error" - IIS Version 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, iis-7.5

[image]

I've developed a web application, I deployed this application on the server.
When I ran the application I am getting `There was an unexpected server error`, that is only error message it shows, no other details.
When I run this application using visual studio, it works just fine. I've tried with below `<customErrors mode="On" />`

- Application pool has been kept in .net version 4.0
- Asp.net has been registered with IIS.

Any ideas would help.

Comment: No other details? Are you sure? There's generally quite a bit more shown than that. Is there any other text on the page?

Comment: Yes, just this message on the page. When i do inspect on the page, console displays "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". Is this what you mean?

Comment: Is [this](http://blog.apterainc.com/hs-fs/hub/213381/file-395186968-png/images/ysod.png?t=1478809630928&width=575&height=403&name=ysod.png) what it looks like?

Comment: No, I can see the application. I have the "Windows Authentication", I read the NT user id of the person who is accessing the application, I display his username with an welcome message, I get this message in place of "User ID". Attached the picture.

Comment: That looks like an error coming from JavaScript. Read over [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is not a client side error, it is server side error.

Comment: The error ultimately comes from the server side, yes. But it appears it's initiated by a JavaScript call. You need to find the call, figure out what it's calling on the server, figure out why that's failing, etc. That's why I asked you to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We do not have access to your source code, it's on *you* to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: Don't mistake me, I am able to deploy this application on a different IIS server (both 7.5 and 10) , and able to run perfectly fine. Only on this server i am getting this issue. Anyways I will also check what you said.

Answer (score 0):

on server web.config try below config. you should see detailed error message.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed"></httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Tried, Still the same error message. No detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

There was a network issue, which has been fixed, and it worked. Asp.net Impersonation has been "Enabled", Anonymous Authentication has been "Disabled". Enabled delegation [for kerberos] for the machine at the AD level. These made application work. There was no code issue at all as expected.